# FTIR baseline subtraction - how to do this properly?

Tags: spectroscopy, infrared-radiation

I am trying to flatten my FTIR spectrum, however I have no Idea how to treat the far-left peak. The spectrum tends to go up in that direction, so in the variant no.1 (see attached picture) I'm trying to set baseline to follow the trend. However I don't know how to interpolate this spectrum, so maybe making baseline flat in that region is okay (variant 2)?

[image]

Or maybe in that case, baseline subtraction is an unnecessary guess and it's better to analyse it the way it is?

Comment: What are you plotting? There cannot be negative value? I even thought you show single beam. And are you perhaps working with a pi-conjugated system?

Comment: @Alchimista Data on the left are original. There's no negative values, as you said. On the right there are negative values because i subtracted the baseline. I don't know if it's conjugated. It's Polyacrylic acid PAAH

Comment: What you are trying to do is generally not necessary if the spectrum is well recorded. I suppose you have a commercial spectrometer, else than ask advice to whom constructed! Next time you seek for advice put labels on your graph, such as transmittance and wavenumber. The latter possibly divided and labelled 100 or 250 spaced. :) easy to read! Now that you told what is, it looks ok, still it has to be a single beam spectrum. You have what looks like the signal of your detector, without any correction for the empty chamber. Am I correct? It is not very easy to judge without knowing how physi..

Comment: .. physically the sample looks like. It is clear what I mean? Feel free to ask!

Comment: In case you are really new to this https://chemistry.oregonstate.edu/courses/ch361-464/ch362/irinstrs.htm